# MATLAB vector element conflict.

Tags: matlab, vector, element

I have been having trouble getting rid of this error. I have read several similar question, but I just must be overlooking something very simple. The following code uses ODE45. There are 3 initial conditions, and it appears to me that my function outputs 3 variables as well. However, it says:

"??? Error using ==> odearguments at 116
DBTS returns a vector of length 2, but the length of initial
conditions vector is 3. The vector returned by DBTS and the
initial conditions vector must have the same number of elements."

This is my m-file:

```
function dDdt=Dbts(t,i)
global p1 p2 p3 n V1 Gb Ib U 

I=i(1);
X=i(2);
G=i(3);

dIdt=-(n*(I-Ib))+(U/V1);
dXdt=-(p2*X)+(p3*I);
dGdt=-(p1*G)-(X*(G-Gb))+(9.0*exp(-0.05*t));

dDdt=[dIdt;dXdt;dGdt];
```

This is what I put into main:

```
global p1 p2 p3 n V1 Gb Ib
p1=0.028735;
p2=0.0228344;
p3=.00005035;
n=.0926;
V1=12;
Gb=81;
Ib=15;
global G X I U
TT=[];
SS=[];
i0=[0 0 0];
tspan=[0 400];
[t,i]=ode45(@Dbts,tspan,i0);
```

At this point the error I posted above comes up. I know I must have miscalculated something here, but I just can't pinpoint it. If anyone could please help with this, I would be extremely grateful. All I have to do is plot 3 graphs when I fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because `U` isn't defined:

```
>> size(U)
ans =

   0   0
```

so the size of `DiDt` is `0x0` and consequently the output of `Dbts` is `2x1`.

Comment: The same goes for `G`, `X` and `I`.

Comment: Ah, I completely overlooked the size of U. Thank you so much. G, I and X where fine because I define them in the initial conditions. Its always easier to solve a problem with a fresh set of eyes. Thanks again!